# Can not get metadata of HEIF/HEIC file in xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, heif

I am playing with the HEIF depth image using xcode.  The problem is that I can not get any metadata; when I use CGImageSourceCopyProperties(image, nil), it always returns nil.  [image]

Comment: having the same issues.. I have tried pretty much all the techniques they show at the WWDC event and nothing works. It's almost like the functionalities not actually there yet. Let me know if you figure anything out and Ill do the same

Comment: Have you found the solution?